# How to append zero to a number based on another number?

Tags: php, loops, numbers

I have a number named `$balance_num = 3;` and I need to make `1000`. See `3` means three `0`s.

Another example, `$balance_num = 1;`, the output should be `10`. One zero.

Any idea how can I do that?

---

Currently I do that using a loop like this:

```
$res = 1;
$balance_num = 3;
for ($i = 0; $i < $balance_num; $i++){
    $res .= 0;
}
echo (int) $res;
```

Any better idea?

Comment: pow(10,$balance_num);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... simply "adding" a zero at the end of an integer in base 10 is the equivalent of multiplying by 10, thus you can simply multiply your input with `10 ^ $balance_num`.

```
$res = 1;
$balance_num = 3;

echo $res * pow(10, $balance_num);
```

Output: `1000`

[pow docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php)

Answer (score 1):

Use str_pad this will help in a short way

1. first argument = your input value.
2. second argument = how many times you want to append.
3. third argument = what you want to append.

   ```
   $one = 1;
   $two  = 4;
   $result = str_pad($one,  $two, "0");
   ```

   Output `1000`

Read more about [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)

Comment: No problem @Martin AJ,  Up-vote  for your question as well :)

Comment: Integers are not strings

Comment: There is also a (int) function in php .@Martin AJ is already using , And converting from string to int is far easier than multiplication. Multiplication gonna take time, I am new in stack-overflow but not in php FYI @Emile

Comment: @LalitOnclick Not at all implying you're new to PHP. Anyway - that's not a function. And because it's possible, doesn't mean it's the right way.